# Mysql batch update locking on innodb

Tags: mysql

If I do a query such as this:

```
UPDATE atable SET avalue = 0 WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM anotherTable WHERE id > 0 AND id < 1000)
```

On an innodb table. Do all the rows with id between 0 and 1000 on `anotherTable` and/or `table` get locked all at once, or would they all get locked one at a time?

Comment: Does this even run? and what's the logic behind it?

Comment: Yes and nothing, I just want to know about the locking

Comment: Actually no it didnt because `table` was a keyword. oops.

Comment: Ive switched the logic up in the query slightly, question is still the same

Comment: check this, it may be a possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/a/2824382/1951298